# CSS Background-position not working with percentages

Tags: android, html, css, cross-browser

I defined a container with background properties like this

```
.container {
  background:url(path/to/image) cover fixed;
  background-position: 70% 60%;
}
```

Tested this on chrome and iphone - works good. But not on android browser. 
If I use `background-position:px px;` it works in android. I like the position when it is in percentages. Any method which will work for all browsers ?

Comment: I was going to say use calc() as this post suggests http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201302/css_background-position_and_percent/ but that doesn't appear to be supported by Android Browser either.